# Which is the best type of web service Rest,Jaxb,XFire etc to develop an big webapplications?

Tags: web-services

I am developing web application to get reading from hardware unit and store it to database  it is an big web application so i need to use web services to get reading which will be good to use in netbeans6.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it depends what web services your hardware supports. If it does not support REST u cant use REST. Check what your hardware supports, it could also be SOAP or even XML/RPC given its a piece of hardware.

If it is REST u could then use Jersey, the JAX-RS implementation that comes with Netbeans. if it is SOAP u can also use JAX-Ws supplied by Netbeans (Metro).  CXF (the latest version of xfire) is also a very good option for SOAP, but u have to include the jar files separately and netbeans WS tools wont be available for it (not that i like using them anyway).

Jaxb is just an implementation to transform xml to java and vice versa. Jax-ws uses jaxb, so unless u are transferring plain xml it would be unlikely to use it directly ( u would still need its jars for jaxws)